# JPA2: composite keys (unable to map)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to map using JPA2 the following database structure:

```
ASSET
ID: assetId
...

PARTY
ID: partyId
...

PARTYASSET
ID: partyId
ID: assetId
ID: relationshipType
```

The primary key of PARTYASSET is a composite of the foreign keys of PARTY and ASSET and an additional column: relationshipType.

Because of the column relationshipType, I cannot use the @ManyToMany annotation I have to use the @ManyToOne and @OneToMany as described in this link:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

I have tried the following guide, which was not helpful:
http://www.kawoolutions.com/Technology/JPA,_Hibernate,_and_Co./JPA_Composite_Key_Variants#JPA_2.0_@IdClass

Could you please help me?

I have tried the followings:
(The inheritance is for other purposes)

*Party class*

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("PARTY")
public class Party implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long partyId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "party")
    private Set<PartyAsset> partyAsset;
    ... 
}
```

*Asset class*

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("ASSET")
public class Asset implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long assetid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "asset")
    private Set<PartyAsset> partyAsset;
    ...
}
```

### **Using @IdClass:**

*PartyAsset class*

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PartyAssetPK.class)
public class PartyAsset implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static enum RelationshipType {
        OWNER, TENANT, SECONDARY_CONTACT, SUPPLIER
    }

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RelationshipType relationshipType;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="partyId")
    private Party party;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="assetId")
    private Asset asset;
    ...
}
```

*PartyAssetPK class*

```
public class PartyAssetPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long partyId;
    private Long assetId;
    private PartyAsset.RelationshipType relationshipType;
}
```

The code above throws the exception:

> Property of @IdClass not found in entity PartyAsset: assetId

### **Alternative of @IdClass**

*PartyAsset class*

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PartyAssetPK.class)
public class PartyAsset implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long partyId;
    @Id
    private Long assetId;

    public static enum RelationshipType {
        OWNER, TENANT, SECONDARY_CONTACT, SUPPLIER
    }

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RelationshipType relationshipType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="partyId")
    @MapsId("partyId")
    private Party party;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="assetId")
    @MapsId("assetId")
    private Asset asset;    
}
```

This throws the exception:

> No supertype found

### **Using @EmbeddedId**

*PartyAsset class*

```
@Entity
public class PartyAsset implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    public PartyAssetPK id;

    public static enum RelationshipType {
        OWNER, TENANT, SECONDARY_CONTACT, SUPPLIER
    }

    @MapsId("relationshipType")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RelationshipType relationshipType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="partyId")
    @MapsId("partyId")
    private Party party;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="assetId")
    @MapsId("assetId")
    private Asset asset;    
}
```

*PartyAssetPK class*

```
@Embeddable
public class PartyAssetPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long partyId;
    private Long assetId;
    private PartyAsset.RelationshipType relationshipType;
}
```

This throws the exception;

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in
>   class
>   com.ardan1.propertymanagement.test.config.TestApplicationContext:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.setType(SimpleValueBinder.java:227)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:188)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2013)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2385)

I have the following libraries (using Maven):

```
<hibernate.version>4.1.2</hibernate.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This eludes the question, but why don't you simply use a technical, non-composite, autogenerated ID for the PartyAsset entity. It would be sooo much easier!

Comment: Is exception in embeddable case is the most bottom part in the stacktrace? If not, please give the most bottom thing in stacktrace

Comment: JB Nizet, thank you for you comment. You might be right about the simplicity using an autogenerated ID, however, I want to stick to the database structure.

Comment: JMelnik, yes, that stacktrace is the last thing that appears in my console.

Comment: you could map the PartyAsset as component (embeddable) and the collection as component collection

Answer (score 0):

I think you could map using the @JoinColumn. The follow code use the Spring Data JPA.

BaseEntity.java

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

public abstract class BaseEntity<PK extends Serializable> extends AbstractPersistable<PK> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 201304010827L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
    }

}
```

AssetEntity.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_asset")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "AssetID"))
public class AssetEntity extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "desc")
    private String desciption;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

PartyEntity.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_party")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "PartyID"))
public class PartyEntity extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private String party;

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

To use the @JoinColumn and @Embeddable we have the PartyAsset.java.

```java
@Embeddable
public class PartyAssetKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "party_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private PartyEntity partyEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "asset_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private AssetEntity assetEntity;

    private Long relationshipType;

}
```

And finally the PartyAssetEntity.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_party_asset")
public class PartyAsset extends BaseEntity<PartyAssetKey> {

    private Long type;

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

I wrote a post about the Spring Data JPA in portuguese: http://wpattern.com/blog/post/2012/11/25/Introducao-ao-Spring-Data-JPA-(Contextualizacao)-Parte-01.aspx

Cya.

Answer (score 0):

@Techky u did a great job by trying all options for Composite key, and coincidently i also got the exact same errors for all the scenario.

for the case Using @EmbeddedId, here is my solution. This code I have written in one class itself, in Entity class.

- Class MyEntity - It is my actual Entity class for my table. "OtherFields" are those fields which are not part of primary key.
- Class MyEntityPrimaryKeys   - It is the class made for my composite key which makes a primary key for my "MyEntity" class. Here ROLLNO and AGE together makes a primary key.

MyEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable")
public class MyEntity extends GenericPersistableEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId 
    MyEntityPrimaryKeys id;//Composite Primary key

    //Composite fields can be declared here for getter and setters
    @Column(name = "ROLLNO")
    private Long RollNo;

    //Composite fields can be declared here for getter and setters
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Long age;

    @Column(name = "OtherFields"
    private Long OtherFields;

    //getter and setters comes here
}



@Embeddable
 class MyEntityPrimaryKeys  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ROLLNO")
    Long RollNo;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    Long age;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder();
        hcb.append(RollNo);
        hcb.append(age);
        return hcb.toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof MyEntityPrimaryKeys)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyEntityPrimaryKeys that = (MyEntityPrimaryKeys) obj;
        EqualsBuilder eb = new EqualsBuilder();
        eb.append(RollNo, that.RollNo);
        eb.append(age, that.age);
        eb.append(tonMonth, that.tonMonth);
        eb.append(tonYear, that.tonYear);
        return eb.isEquals();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!